# Punctuation with embedded questions

Tags: grammar, questions, punctuation

Is it grammatical? You either put a period or use inverted order, don't you?

> Tell us how **you would** try to understand the people at the heart of the problem that you care about?

Mind! I'm not asking you to "find and correct errors or improve the phrasing". Instead, I focus on something in particular, order of appearance of subjects and auxiliary verbs in embedded questions (whether it could be inversed or not)

Comment: It's OK as it is. Subordinate interrogatives don't normally have inversion.

Comment: @BillJ but they normally don't have question marks either, do they?

Comment: That's right. Subordinate interrogatives express questions, but they don't themselves ask them. Please see my answer.

Comment: @BillJ but the example sentence has the question mark! Are you okay with that? Is it grammatically allowed?

Comment: I was referring to the clausal structure. The question mark is wrong, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @BillJ you didn't explicitly say it was wrong, though. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Despite your edit to clarify that you're not looking for proofreading, I still don't know what aspect of English you're asking about nor which part of the sentence it appears in. The order of appearance *of what*?? Also, please focus our attention on the parts of the sentence that might be inverted **in bold** or [with] [brackets].

Answer (score 3):

> *Tell us* [*how you would try to understand the people at the heart of the*
> *problem that you care about*].

It's OK as it is, but note that although the embedded clause is an interrogative one, it does not require a question mark, and nor does the matrix clause that contains it, which here is an imperative not an interrogative. Note that subordinate interrogatives don't normally have inversion.

The meaning can be glossed as

> "*Tell us the answer to the question 'How would you try to understand the people* *at the heart of the problem that you care about?'"*

Comment: "*I've posted an answer which I hope is clearer than my comment!*" — Yes, thanks.  (But I'd put a `.` (or `!`) after the final quotation mark. :-)

Comment: You can do without inversion, but still put a question mark, is that correct?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev No: as I said in my answer, there should **not** be a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your sentence is correct as is without inversion, but the question mark is incorrect.

Question marks are only for sentences that are questions, that's to say *interrogative sentences*. Your sentence begins with "*Tell us...*", which makes the sentence *imperative*, not *interrogative*. None of the rest of the sentence will change that it's an imperative sentence.

The structure of the main clause is the same as:

> Tell us ***something***.

Here, "something" is the direct object of "tell" and represents ***the information*** to tell is.

The phrase, "***how you would try to understand the people at the heart of the problem that you care about***" is a *noun clause* that represents that information. This phrase is *not a question at all*. It uses the interrogative pronoun "how", but *not to ask a question*.

The name "interrogative pronoun" is misleading. These pronouns are *not just for questions*. They are used to indicate missing information. This makes them very useful in questions because if we have to ask, it means we don't know the information. But there's plenty of other contexts where it's useful to have pronouns that represent missing information.

In your sentence, "how" is a placeholder pronoun for information that the speaker doesn't have. It could be replaced with the phrase, "the way (that)", which is clearly just a noun representing the missing information, not a question.

This means no inversion, and no question mark.